# Load picture using an URL MYSQL

Tags: mysql, picturegallery

I want to know If there is any way to load an image into a table like:

`CREATE TABLE MyTable(
id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
images BLOB NOT NULL,`

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (image) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('/tmp/your_image.png'));
```

But also if i can add an url instead of the path to my image:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (image) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('https://imgur.com/gallery/6rKiG'));
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO x(id,pic) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('C:/Desktop/images/test.jpg'));
```

And then with PHP (for example) you can read and print

```
/*
Read from database
...
... */
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['pic'] ).'"/>';
```

For reference [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)